# Synchronize RecyclerView data between two devices?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, synchronization, android-room

Goodmorning everyone. I have a simple to do list that saves data with RoomDatabase and shows the results on a RecyclerView. Now I would like the elements of my list to sync also on another device, where my app is installed. I would like that, by performing any of the CRUD operations on the first device, the second device also changes automatically. Does Room DB have features that can do this? What are the right steps I should take to achieve my goal? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is LiveData.

There are really nice tutorials from Android Jetpack team:

- How to connect Room with RxJava (e.g. LiveData):
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM
- LiveData explained:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMcDk2_4LSk
- Code examples:
  https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think LiveData would be able to Sync data between multiple devices.
Too bad my English is bad and it will be difficult for me to understand the words of the videos. But thank you for showing me the way